# Webcam doesn't work in java

Tags: java

It is not logic ? because I added the webcam panel to the frame. So it normally shows a view of my webcam inside the JFrame.
Anyone can help to to view the webcam really into the JFrame view ?
After my researches on google, I didn't find how to do it.

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author matr
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
            webcam.open();
            ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(), "PNG", new File("hello-world.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    private void formComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
        WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        panel.setFPSDisplayed(true);
        panel.setDisplayDebugInfo(true);
        panel.setImageSizeDisplayed(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        this.add(panel);
    }                                   



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }

        });

    }



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

Comment: Reducing your code to a minimal example which allows to reproduce your problem will attract more and faster help.

Comment: Do you have any errors ? what doesn't work?

Comment: I have no error but the frame is not showing myself though the webcam

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the auto-generated UI code. The `WebcamPanel` is added to the frame but the auto-generated code effectively makes the `WebcamPanel` invisible. Try to use the `WebcamPanel` in a simpler UI and it will work; it worked fine for me.

## Update for the edit:

The WebcamPanel is nowhere added to the content pane of the `JFrame`. Add the WebcamPanel properly to the content pane of the `JFrame` and it will show.